# Как правильно делать jpql запросы и заносить их в коллекцию?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, коллекции

Делаю запрос на добавление в List всей таблицы

```
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomCourse, Long> {
@Query("SELECT * FROM CustomCourse")
CustomCourse findAllCourses();
}
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean

Ругается на метод, так как он без параметров, но понятия не имею что там указать, ведь я забираю таблицу целиком а не делаю выборку по какому то полю.

Comment: where 1=?, и подставить 1

Comment: У `JpaRepository` уже есть метод `findAll`, пользуйтесь ним, к тому же метод должен быть `List<CustomCourse> findAllCourses();`

Comment: Спасибо, вы помогли мне. В добавок хочу заметить что я делал SQL запрос, а надо было JPQL делать.

Comment: Измените свой вопрос и допишите, что Вам помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых мой запроc "SELECT * FROM CustomCourse" являлся SQL запросом, а правильнее было сделать JPQL запрос "SELECT c FROM CustomCourse c" раз пользуемся JPA и Hibernate.

Во вторых MrFylypenko правильно указал что необходимо было сделать метод List findAllCourses(); Это позволяет обходиться без циклов, и  вообще упрощает мою работу.

метод findAll у JpaRepository тоже работает.

В итоге мой код выглядит так

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM CustomCourse c")
ArrayList<CustomCourse> findAll();
```